# Regex pattern matching with a variable number of matching capturing groups

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

A text file should be parsed line by line, using Scala pattern matching and regular expressions. If a line starts with `"names:\t"` the subsequent tab-separated names should be provided as a `Seq[String]` (or something similar).

Here a non-working code example:

```scala
val Names = "^names:(?:\t([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))+$".r

"names:\taaa\tbbb\tccc" match {
  case Names(names @ _*) => println(names)
  // […] other cases
  case _ => println("no match")
}
```

Output: `List(ccc)` 
Wanted output: `List(aaa, bbb, ccc)`

The following code works as desired…

```scala
object NamesObject {
  private val NamesLine = "^names:\t([a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\t[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*)$".r

  def unapplySeq(s: String): Option[Seq[String]] = s match {
    case NamesLine(nameString) => Some(nameString.split("\t"))
    case _ => None
  }
}

"names:\taaa\tbbb\tccc" match {
  case NamesObject(names @ _*) => println(names)
  // […] other cases
  case _ => println("no match")
}
```

Output (as wanted): `WrappedArray(aaa, bbb, ccc)`

I would like to know: **Is this is possible in a simpler manner without creating an `object`, just like in the first but non-working code example?**

Comment: The Scala `RegEx` extractor is a _match_, not a _find_, so the `^` and `$` are redundant. If you want _find_ semantics, you need `.*` at the beginning and / or end. (Not relevant to the problem you're trying to solve, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Randall Schulz said, it seems not to be possible just using regular expressions. Therefore the short answer to my question would be *no*.

My current solution is the following: I use the this class…

```scala
class SeparatedLinePattern(Pattern: Regex, separator: String = "\t") {
  def unapplySeq(s: String): Option[Seq[String]] = s match {
    case Pattern(nameString) => Some(nameString.split(separator).toSeq)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

…to create the patterns:

```scala
val Names = new SeparatedLinePattern("""names:\t([A-Za-z]+(?:\t[A-Za-z]+)*)""".r)
val Ints = new SeparatedLinePattern("""ints:\t(\d+(?:\t\d+)*)""".r)
val ValuesWithID = new SeparatedLinePattern("""id-value:\t(\d+\t\w+(?:\t\d+\t\w+)*)""".r)
```

Here an example how they can be used in a quite flexible manner:

```scala
val testStrings = List("names:\taaa", "names:\tbbb\tccc", "names:\tddd\teee\tfff\tggg\thhh",
                       "ints:\t123", "ints:\t456\t789", "ints:\t100\t200\t300",
                       "id-value:\t42\tbaz", "id-value:\t2\tfoo\t5\tbar\t23\tbla")

for (s <- testStrings) s match {
  case Names(name) => println(s"The name is '$name'")
  case Names(a, b) => println(s"The two names are '$a' and '$b'")
  case Names(names @ _*) => println("Many names: " + names.mkString(", "))

  case Ints(a) => println(s"Just $a")
  case Ints(a, b) => println(s"$a + $b == ${a.toInt + b.toInt}")
  case Ints(nums @ _*) => println("Sum is " + (nums map (_.toInt)).sum)

  case ValuesWithID(id, value) => println(s"ID of '$value' is $id")
  case ValuesWithID(values @ _*) => println("As map: " + (values.grouped(2) map (x => x(0).toInt -> x(1))).toMap)

  case _ => println("No match")
}
```

Output:

```
The name is 'aaa'
The two names are 'bbb' and 'ccc'
Many names: ddd, eee, fff, ggg, hhh
Just 123
456 + 789 == 1245
Sum is 600
ID of 'baz' is 42
As map: Map(2 -> foo, 5 -> bar, 23 -> bla)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your working regex.(`\w` is a predefined character class for`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

```
  val Names = """names:\t(\w+(?:\t\w+)*)""".r
  "names:\taaa\tbbb\tccc" match {
    case Names(names) => println(names.split("\t") toSeq)
    case _ => println("no match")
  }
```

With first, second & tail bindings,

```
  val Names = """names:\t(\w+)?\t?(\w+)?\t?((?:\w+?\t?)*)""".r
  "names:\taaa\tbbb\tccc\tddd" match {
    case Names(first, second, tail) =>
      println(first + ", " + second + ", " + (tail.split("\t") toSeq));
    case _ => println("no match")
  }
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I believe this is the only solution, namely to parse it in two parts (or use the low-level `RegEx` API, which is less nice than what the OP attempted and this solution).

Comment: This solution is short, but something like `Names(first, second, tail @ _*)` is not possible, but it would be great for flexibility.

Comment: @Radon, answer is updated with first, second and tail binding

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: Thank you for your efforts, but I want it a bit more flexible, e.g. `Names(a)`, `Names(a,b)`, `Names(a,b,c,d)` and `Names(all @ _*)` should be possible, too.